# Get list of 'Friendly interface names' on a Mac (Airport, Ethernet, etc)

Tags: macos, shell, networking, ifconfig

I'm developing an application in RealBASIC, but I need the list of interface names to populate a dropdown box.

Parsing ifconfig didn't work (got `eth0`, `eth1`, `lo`, etc.). I need the name that is displayed in system preferences (Ethernet, Airport, etc.).

Is there a terminal command that I can parse?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`networksetup -listallnetworkservices` will give you just the names (with an asterisk before disabled ports, in case you want to leave them out).  `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` gives some additional info, like what /dev entry (en0, etc) they correspond to.  Check the man page for `networksetup` for even lots more options...